# AJAX POST Not Returning

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, post, asp.net-mvc-4

In my C# MVC4 application, I perform the following AJAX Post:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.rowselection').click(function (e) {
            var tdata = $('#form1').serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: tdata,
                url: "/Home/PartialAverage",
                success: function (result) { success(result); }
            });
        });

        function success(result) {
            $("#Display_Average").html(result);
        }
    });
</script>
```

While running the application on localhost and performing testing, never immediately, but almost always after a considerable amount of time passes, which I click the checkboxes which initiate the POST, the POSTS fail to return in a timely manner or even at all in some instances.  This isn't acceptable because the post refreshes a partial view that displays quickly needed data.

What could be causing this, is it something I can prevent, and is it something I can expect to see once I post to production?

Here is my ActionResult:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PartialAverage(ChViewModel model, FormCollection myFcollection)
{
    HomeModel C = new HomeModel();
    System.Data.DataTable myDT = new System.Data.DataTable();
    myDT = (DataTable)Session["DT"];
    ChViewModel D = new ChViewModel();
    D = model;
    D = C.AverageCalculation(myDT, myFcollection, D);

    ViewData["SampleTypes"] = C.SampleTypeList;
    Session["Counter"] = 0;
        return PartialView(D);
    }
```

Comment: Could you post the site thats causing this?  You need to inspect your traffic using Fiddler or the browser's built-in network monitoring feature.  Can you post the results of that?

Comment: Are there **lots** of checkboxes? Can you post your action method?

Comment: Just to make sure its nothing on server or client end. I suggest you have your POST method hit a server function that simply returns Success.

Comment: @cgation There is no traffic to the site other than myself because its when Im testing using my workingcopy from Visual Studio, running on localhost, IISExpress, etc.  So I dont have a site that I can POST

Comment: @mattytommo No there are never more than 7 or 8 checkboxes.  Ill post the action method shortly

Comment: @mattytommo Ive posted my action method above